# How to download and install latest version MongoDB for windows 7 32bit

Tags: mongodb

I have tried downloading mangodb from the official website but its showing "no need to download and build a cluster online" .Help me out.

Comment: Click "Community Server" tab

Comment: @Héctor its showing for 64bit and thats the only option in thee dropdown

Comment: Look at (https://www.mongodb.org/dl/win32) and choose `.msi`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

32-bit x86 builds of MongoDB were [deprecated in 3.2](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/release-notes/3.2/#platform-support) and removed as of MongoDB 3.4. [32-bit builds](https://www.mongodb.com/blog/post/32-bit-limitations) are only suitable for development purposes and have significant limitations: they only support the MMAP storage engine, small data sets (~2GB without journaling or half of that with journal enabled), and do not include SSL.

You can still download older Windows 32-bit releases by choosing [Previous Releases](https://www.mongodb.com/download-center#previous) in the Download Center, selecting 3.2.x, and then Windows.

The "No download necessary" alternative is to use [MongoDB Atlas](https://altas.mongodb.com/), which is a hosted database-as-a-service where you can get started using the free tier (512MB of data, WiredTiger storage engine, MongoDB 3.4+).